# Sending a dictionary using WCF, WSBinding

Tags: c#, wcf, dictionary, wshttpbinding

I am currently trying to create a webservice in a winform application using WCF, WShttpBinding. One of the methods returns a dictionary. The client side, an RTD Server will call this method to retrieve the dictionary.

For some reason, when the dictionary gets too large( 0.6MB +), a communication exception will be thrown. I have tried increasing the size of the following parameters both on the clientside and serverside, but it still willnot work. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

```
binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize
binding.MaxBufferPoolSize
binding.SendTimeout 
binding.OpenTimeout
binding.ReceiveTimeout 
binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength 
binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxDepth 
binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxBytesPerRead
```

Comment: Does this solve your problem?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426490/wcf-service-communication-exception-due-to-parameter-size

Comment: please provide exception for getting the exact solution, also consider changing binding parameters at service and client both sides. my general guess is, try returning same data with list(of T) in place of dictionary may fix that.

Comment: Here is the following message from the exception: An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to http://localhost:8000/ServerName/Service/Service. This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details. I am definately using WShttpBinding on both server and client, do I don't know whats up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `behavior` configuration in your `App.config` files:

- On the server:

```
<behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MyServiceBehavior">
            <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
        </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

- On the client:

```
<behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MyClientBehavior">
            <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
        </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Note that `2147483647` is the max value and maybe you don't need that much.

---

And don't forget to reference the behavior in your services and endpoints:

- On your server (and on your client if it hosts some services):

```
<service name="SomeService" behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceBehavior">
    <endpoint binding="WShttpBinding" 
              bindingConfiguration="MyBindingConf" 
              contract="SomeContract"/>
</service>
```

- On your client:

```
<endpoint binding="WShttpBinding" 
          bindingConfiguration="MyBindingConf"
          behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceBehavior" 
          contract="SomeContract" 
          name="SomeName" />
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this outside of an app.config file? The RTD server is part of excel. I ran into a problem reading from the app.config before, so I have been creating the bindings in the code. Thanks

Comment: @Alvin: Sorry, maybe it is possible but I don't know how. Does the `maxItemsInObjectGraph` solve your problem?

Comment: The RTD Server runs as part of Excel, so you can add the configuration for the service into the app.config for Excel (Excel.exe.config). Not sure if this is the nicest solution though :S